# 'Not ilike any' clause with wildcard from an array doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql

Just as in title, following code doesn't filter anything at all, it returns all rows while without 'NOT' it works just fine. Where's the problem?

```
create table test (value text);

    insert into test values
    ('Test1'),
    ('foo'),
    ('bar'),
    ('foobar'),
    ('foobar2'),
    ('foobar3'),
    ('foo1bar'),
    ('foo bar'),
    ('barbar');
    
    select *
    FROM test
    WHERE value NOT like any (array['%foo%', '%foo bar%', '%xx%'])
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gCFy3K97gQy7gxomAL2Qm7/0

Comment: If you use `like any`, I don't see `'Test1'`, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Damn, I missed 'NOT' in code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean `not like any` is not working.  And I think that is because you want `not like all`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE value  like all (array['%foo%', '%foo bar%', '%xx%'])
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j46q7oiGsBwangA7bozART/0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, 'all' instead of any solved it, thank you